# One half dread, one half excitement

Tags: verbs

This sentence:

> I half dread half excited for that.

is obviously wrong, because separately it'd be

I dread that

or

I am excited for that

But I do not now how to say it together. Can you please give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it is a bit awkward because the two phrases have different verbs, but there are several ways you could change the grammar or verb tenses to construct a sentence with these two thoughts together.

> I am half dreading and half excited for that.
> I feel half dread and half excitement for that.
> I half dread that and am half excited for it.
> I'm half in dread and half excited for that.